# To what extent DLLs speed up calculations in a code such as loops etc

Tags: c++, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, dll

I have a code with a loop that counts to 10000000000, and within that loop, I do some calculations with conditional operators (if etc). It takes about 5 minutes to reach that number. so, my question is, can I reduce the time it takes by creating a DLL and call that dll for functions to do the calculation and return the values to the main program? will it make a difference in time it takes to do the calculations? further, will it improve the overall efficiency of the program?

Comment: Why would you think a DLL would have any aspect on the performance? A function is a function, it makes no difference where it's located.

Comment: Maybe [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx) could help. But without seeing code it is hard to say.

Comment: Thank you OneFineDay, :) . I'm gonna try it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By a “dll” I assume you mean going from managed .net code to that of un-managed “native” compiled code. Yes this approach can help.

It much depends. Remember, the speed of the loop code is likely only 25 seconds on a typical i3 (that is the cost and overhead to loop to 10 billion but doing much nothing else).

And I assumed you went to the project, then compile. On that screen select advanced compile. There you want to check remove integer overflow checks. Make sure you loop vars are integers for speed.

At that point the “base” loop that does nothing will drop from about 20 seconds down to about 6 seconds.

So that is the base loop speed – now it come down to what we are doing inside of that loop.

At this point, .net DOES HAVE a JIT (a just in time native compiler). This means your source code goes to “CLR” code and then in tern that code does get compiled down to native x86 assembly code. So this “does” get the source code down to REAL machine code level. However a JIT is certainly NOT as efficient nor can it spend “time” optimizing the code since the JIT has to work on the “fly” without you noticing it. So a c++ (or VB6 which runs as fast as c++ when native compiled) can certainly run faster, but the question then is by how much?

The optimized compiler might get another double in speed for the actually LOOPING code etc.

However, in BOTH cases (using .net managed code, or code compiled down to native Intel code), they BOTH LIKELY are calling the SAME routines to do the math!

In other words, if 80% of the code is spend in “library” code that does the math etc., then calling such code from c++ or calling such code from .net will make VERY LITTLE difference since the BULK of the work is spend in the same system code!

The above concept is really “supervisor” mode vs. your application mode.

In other words, the amount of time spent in your code vs. that of using system “library” code means that the bulk of the heaving lifting is occurring in supervisor code. That means jumping from .net to native c++/vb6 dll’s will NOT yield much in the way of performance.

So I would first ensure loops and array index refs in your code are integer types. The above tip of taking off bounds checking likely will give you “close” to that of using a .dll. Worse is often the time to “shuffle” the data two and from that external.dll sub will cost you MORE than the time saved on the processing side.

And if your routines are doing database or file i/o, then all bets are off, as that is VERY different problem.

So I would first test/try your application with [x] remove integer overflow checks turned off. And make sure during testing that you use ctrl-F5 in place of F5 to run your code without DEBUGGING. The above overflow check and options will NOT show increased speed when in debug mode.

So it hard to tell – it really depends on how much math (especially floating calls) you are doing (supervisor code) vs. that of just moving values around in arrays. If more code is moving things around, then I suggest the integer optimizing above, and going to a .dll likely will not help much.

Comment: Thank you Albert for the detailed answer, I tried disabling integer overflow checks etc and running ctrl-F5. It certainly improves it's speed by about 30%, but speed doesn't increase after building the project, the standalone exe file doesn't produce the same speed.I don't know why it didn't produce the same result.

Comment: Your resulting app should run at least as well as the ctrlF5. Something is wrong here.  I would create a non debug build. I would also try forcing the application to x32 (x86) and see if that runs better. And might as well try x64 also.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn´t you utilize "Parallel.ForEach" and strip this huge loop in some equal pieces?

Or try to work with some Backgroundworkers or even Threads (more than 1!!) to achieve the optimal CPU performance and try to reduce the spent time.

Comment: Thank you David BS, :) . I'm gonna try it :)

Comment: You´re welcome. If you have doubts about it, let me know. Hugs!